# Looking for all descendant elements which parent does not have this css class

Tags: xpath

I am trying to get all children which has specific class and parent of this parent does not have a specific class.

I am trying a code like this, but it's not working.

```
$hrefs = $xpath->evaluate("//div[not contains(@class, 'tested-app-section')]/div[@class='product-container-body']/div");
```

Structure of the HTML I am working with and need to edit a little bit looks like this, other HTML content in `<body>` is irrelevant. (`<body>` contains more then just this block of HTML):

```
<body>
  <div class="product-detail-section tested-app-section">
    <div class="product-container-head"> ... </div>
    <div class="product-container-body"> ... </div>
    <div class="product-container-body"> ... </div>
  </div>
  <div class="product-detail-section publish-app-section">
    <div class="product-container-head"> ... </div>
    <div class="product-container-body"> ... </div>
    <div class="product-container-body"> ... </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="product-detail-section product-specific-section">
    <div class="product-container-head"> ... </div>
    <div class="product-container-body"> ... </div>
    <div class="product-container-body"> ... </div>
  </div>
```

I am trying to avoid in the result the very first `<div>` box (box with class `"tested-app-section"`), then I am trying to avoid everything witch class `"product-container-head"`.

But I just cannot find a way how to do it.

Edit: So basically I am trying to get

```
/html/body/div[contains(@class, 'product-detail-section') AND not contains(@class, 'tested-app-section')]/div[not(@class='product-container-head')]
```

but this code doesn't return anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close, but missed a few things. Try this xpath expression and see if it works:

```
//div[not(contains(@class, 'tested-app-section'))]/div[not(@class='product-container-head')]
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! I messed up at a first copy paste, added one more `/` so it didn't work at first try because of that small mistake on my side, thank you very much!